# Setting up wildcard subdomain on ubuntu 14.04 with a2ensite?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-14.04, wildcard-subdomain

I am using apache on ubuntu 14.04.  I set up a wildcard domain for my site but it isn't working how I would like it to.  I want

```
www.example.com --> /var/www/mysite
example.com --> /var/www/mysite
```

and everything else to go to

```
*.example.com --> /var/www/myothersite
```

BUT, Right now it is working like this

```
example.com --> /var/www/mysite
```

and

```
www.example.com --> /var/www/myothersite
*.example.com --> /var/www/myothersite
```

I created the virtual hosts by creating two conf files in sites-available/

```
example.com.conf
catchall.example.com.conf
```

Here is the contents of example.com.conf

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
```

Here is the contents of catchall.example.com.conf

```
ServerName catchall.example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/myothersite
```

After I created the files I ran a2ensite on the files and reloaded apache.  Any idea on how I can achieve the results I am looking for while still using sites-available and a2ensite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that Apache parses Included configuration files in lexicographical order and catchall.example.com.conf is parsed before example.com.conf.

The result is that `www.example.com` is matched with  `*.example.com` , rather than the explicit ServerAlias in the example.com.conf file.

The solution is to rename catchall.example.com.conf to something like wildcard.example.com.conf that comes later in the alphabet then example.com.conf.